# Translating VBA to VBScript for removing duplicates in a column

Tags: excel, vbscript

I have a sheet in an Excel file in which I want to remove duplicate values from column 1. In Excel it has this feature when you click under Data, then Remove Duplicates on the column named "Code" which is the first column. I am trying to translate this as a VBScript, unsure how. I tried recording a macro to grab the VBA syntax but it isn't the same for VBScript. The code I get from the recorded macro is

```
Sub Macro1()
    Columns("A:A").Select
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$K$523").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlYes
End Sub
```

Comment: Show us your existing VBScript. Do you have the necessary code to open Excel and your workbook?

Comment: Yes, I have the workbooks open and the sheets too. I am just looking for this snippet. I tried doing `ws.Range($A$1:$K$523").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1` But it didn't work.

Comment: [Starting point](http://sdb.planetcobalt.net/vba2vbs.shtml).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't use named parameters in VBScript. You just need to provide parameters in the proper order, as they appear in the function declaration. Also you won't be able to use Excel's constants (`xlNo`, `xlYes`, etc) without first defining them yourself.

For your `RemoveDuplicates()` function, the VBScript equivalent would look like (assuming `objExcel` is your application object):

```
objExcel.ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$K$523").RemoveDuplicates 1
```

Since `Columns` is the first parameter to `RemoveDuplicates()`. If you wanted to specify a header row, it would look like this:

```
Const xlYes = 1
objExcel.ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$K$523").RemoveDuplicates 1, xlYes
```

Comment: Similarly, if i just wanted to remove duplicates in just column A, I could just change the .Range part to `.Range("$A$1").RemoveDuplicates 1` ?

Comment: `$A$1` would only consider that one cell. You'd want to specify a _range_ of cells, like `$A$1:$A$523`.

Answer (score 0):

For me this works:

```
myWorkSheet.UsedRange.RemoveDuplicates array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13)
```

Being 1 to 13 all the columns in the sheet (in my case I consider DUP when the row is ALL equal).
But I don't know how to pass an array object.
This also presents an error:

```
myWorkSheet.UsedRange.RemoveDuplicates array(myArray)
```

OR

```
myWorkSheet.UsedRange.RemoveDuplicates myArray
```

The error on this is normal because "removeduplicates" funct. expects the reserved word "array".

Comment: see  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74314483/vbs-remove-duplicate-rows-in-excel/74345969#74345969 to extend my response