# VBS: remove duplicate rows in excel

Tags: excel, vbscript

i have a script that merge XLS files removing intermediate headers and i want also to remove duplicate rows.

this works(delete the row if columns 1 to 7 are identical):

```
objSheet.UsedRange.RemoveDuplicates array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7)
```

but i want to generalize and pass to this array function, the number of cols of the sheet, but no idea how.

Answer (score -1):

As i cannot pass an array to the array function, i use **execute** method to do it:

```
' create the string with cols and commas
for col=1 to lastcolumn
    colnumbers = colnumbers & col & ","
Next
' delete final comma
colsComma = Left(colnumbers, Len(colnumBers) - 1)
' mount execute line
rmdups = "objSheetDst.UsedRange.RemoveDuplicates array(" & colsComma & ")"
execute(rmdups)
```